# AWS Elastic Transcoder watermarks

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm trying to add a watermark to all my videos being processed through Amazon elastic transcoder but I can't get it to working.

I created the preset with one watermark set(BottomRight) as in docs.

Here's my PHP source

```
$output = array(
  'Key' => $folderNameOut,
  'PresetId' => '139450346',
  'ThumbnailPattern' => 'thumbs/filename-{count}',
  'Watermarks' => array(
  'InputKey' => 'watermark/watermark.png',
  'PresetWatermarkId' => 'BottomRight'
 ));
```

I tried putting the watermark image in both thumbs and video buckets, even HTTP URL but doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: added the settings in BOTH  presets and in jobs

Comment: I did, I created a preset with a watermark set and in jobs as above sample code shows. :/ where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have same problem... can you give me the exact syntax

Comment: Although I am using django, python but It would help for anyone going through this kind of issue. I recently published a post http://aameer.github.io/articles/aws-elastic-encoder/ which enables adding watermarks, I convert the text to image and then use that as watermark

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing array inside the watermarks array

```
$output = array(
 'Key' => $folderNameOut,
 'PresetId' => '139450346',
 'ThumbnailPattern' => 'thumbs/filename-{count}',
 'Watermarks' => array(
  array(
   'InputKey' => 'watermark/watermark.png',
   'PresetWatermarkId' => 'BottomRight'
   )
));
```